# FacebookSDK Objective-c Login blank screen failed for URL: "fbauth2:/"

Tags: objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on an app using objective-c when using FacebookSDKLoginKit, I am pressing login with Facebook, and the give the permission to the app by clicking continue, after that the webview return to blank screen and I get this error:
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

I have checked every thing in my project:

1) I have added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

2) I have added CFBundleURLSchemes

3) In AppDelegate I have added

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                      openURL:url
                                            sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                   annotation:annotation];}
```

and in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

4) I have turned on Keychain Sharing

5) Here my code when I press on FBSDKLoginButton

```
_login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[_login logOut];
[_login setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative];
[_login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult* result, NSError*error)
 {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Process error");
     }
     else if (result.isCancelled) {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                           alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook Access Denied",@"errorLabel")
                                           message:NSLocalizedString(@"Please, recheck your Facebook configuration settings.",@"unknownError")
                                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
             UIAlertAction* okButton = [UIAlertAction
                                        actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Close",@"okLabel")
                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                            return;
                                        }];
             [alert addAction:okButton];
             [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
         });
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Logged in");
         [self pasrseFBData];
     }
 }];
```

** I am using latest FBSDKCoreKit 4.27.0

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts on this..

**ONE:**
In your #3 **openUrl** in **AppDelegate**, you didn't paste the whole block:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

  BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  return handled;
}
```

Full details can be found in [the Facebook SDK Login documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios).

**TWO:**
**Info.plist** needs to be edited as well, like this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fb1234567891011</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>1234567891011</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>NAME OF YOUR APP</string>
```

Replace the "**1234567891011**" twice in there with your own Facebook App ID.  The Facebook SDK docs link above will actually show you your Facebook app ID, if you are logged in.  Note that under **CFBundleURLSchemes** it needs to have "**fb**" followed by the ID number.

**THREE:**
In your Facebook app dashboard, you need to add your app **Bundle ID**, and also enable the checkbox for **Enable Single Sign On**.  These are described in items **3a** and **3b** in the above FB docs link.

**FOUR:**
Your app needs to be set to **Live** on the Facebook dashboard.

**FIVE:**
Enable **Keychain Sharing** in the **Capabilities** tab in Xcode.

**SIX:**
Include both **FBSDKCoreKit** and **FBSDKLoginKit** frameworks.

**SEVEN:**
Test on a real device instead of simulator.

Comment: Same problem @drwester

Comment: Check info.plist as well (described in my edited answer), as well as the bundle ID and single sign on checkbox in the FB dashboard.

Comment: I have already did them, I am now working on a new project because I am thinking that cocoapod affect the project and I think it is the problem

Comment: Same problem even on new project

Comment: Enable keychain sharing in Capabilities in Xcode.  set to live on FB dash.

Comment: I had enabled keychain sharing and the app is live

Comment: Facebook app is installed on the test device?

Comment: No it is not installed

Comment: the failed for fbauth2:/ the error code -10814 is "No application in the Launch Services database matches the input criteria."  This is correct behavior if the app is not installed.  However, the user should still get a web view for authentication.  Are you running on live device or simulator?  Also, did you include both FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit frameworks?

Comment: Yes I included them both, also I am working on simulator and real device I will try to download the app and test it thank you

Comment: I know prior versions did not work properly testing with simulator when FB app was not installed.

Comment: Aha, thank you @drewster I will test on a real device with facebook app installed